# Support cones and linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be any set. A convex cone $C$ with apex $a$ and non-empty interior is a *support cone* of $S$ at $a$ if

i) $a \in S,$

ii) $S \subset (\text{int} \;C)^{\complement}$ (i.e complement of $(\text{int} 
\;C)$) and,

iii) $C$ is a maximal (with respect to inclusion) convex cone with these properties.

My question is, will $(\text{int} 
\;C)^{\complement}$ be a closed half space or the kernel of a linear functional $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ like that of a support plane?

A text reference will also be really appreciated.

Comment: how does $a$ relate to $C$? is $a\in C$ as well?

Comment: $a$ is the apex of $C$.

Comment: Could you please define the apex?

Comment: A set $C\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ is a cone if there exists a point $a\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $]0,\infty[.(C-a)\subset C-a.$ The point $a$ is called the apex of the cone $C,$ and it does not necessarily belong to the cone.

Answer (score 0):

This will not always be true; see [this counterexample](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3txx8qv2pq).

For the open, non-convex (yellow) "pac-man" set $S$, we see that the (red) open support cone emanating from its "mouth" is not a halfspace. Furthermore, since it is a nonlinear set, it cannot be the kernel of a linear functional.

For good references on convex cones, I'd recommend Rockafellar's book on Convex analysis, as well as Bauschke/Combettes' book on Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator theory (2nd edition, Chapter 6).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to know if for a cone, does it have any linear function associated with it in any way?

Comment: @user332905 the counterexample above demonstrates that there is not always a linear functional associated to a cone -- so the answer is no :(